# Should we make an FAQ question for reading battery date codes?

Tags: discussion

Maybe we should make an FAQ (or wiki) for reading battery date codes. Several similar questions about different brands:

[How do I know when a car battery was produced?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/2814/how-do-i-know-when-a-car-battery-was-produced)

[Interpreting AC Delco's manufacturing date for car batteries](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/18888/interpreting-ac-delcos-manufacturing-date-for-car-batteries)

[Getting information from manufacturing code on Exide car battery](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/18188/getting-information-from-manufacturing-code-on-exide-car-battery)

Answer (score 4):

I've suggested some kind of Wiki or FAQ before for other things, the general consensus being that it seems like a good idea, but isn't something that we can do within the stack exchange platform as-is (especially within a beta environment)

Is this something we should push up to the SE meta? I wonder if it's the sort of thing that would be useful to other sites? We can't be the only one that gets the same kind of questions asked frequently...

Comment: I think we can turn a post into a "community wiki" that would function much in the same manner. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts